# Как правильно передать на сервер csrf-токен с content-type != текст

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

С обычным content-type='Content-Type' и "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" проблем нет. Но все мои попытки отправить на сервер с помощью `FormData` либо `application/json` терпят неудачу. Мои данные,сформированные в json имеют следующий вид:

> {"csrfmiddlewaretoken":"qINAB2CHSgja7tOh9IjUIBfPJ8hTkFKdcNcbs0rbDStDRc8egmtL69IsNDxEnX59","id_Title":"","id_Content":""}:

Но в ответе от сервера я получаю ошибку 403 о неверном csrf.

Я нашел рабочий пример для form-data с jquery [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python-django/thread2426127.html), но я не использую jquery. И мне пока не ясен секрет. Пробовал выставлять заголовок как там:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'])
```

В заголовках смотрел - токен установился - получил:

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

То же самое и при попытке отправить formdata - с ней данные вообще принимают следующий вид:

> ------WebKitFormBoundarysH3gth4rOeR1r8Sr Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
>
> Qme9AMgGBEPitGdCn3I7LWkaEzPfcpy9CrDKrK5amgZLdpxzuHSY9uNNI450fHT5
>   ------WebKitFormBoundarysH3gth4rOeR1r8Sr Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarysH3gth4rOeR1r8Sr Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarysH3gth4rOeR1r8Sr--

По ссылке видел еще какой-то флаг `processData: false`, но в обычном XMLHttpRequest я такого метода не нашел.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобного рода задачами?

Comment: Покажи свои urls.py. 405-я часто из-за перекрытия адресов бывает

Comment: И если вы не используете jq, забудьте про processData. Вы сами форматируете данные как хотите